# Is it possible to combine an else with the rest the scope in C/C++

Tags: c, if-statement, boolean, boolean-logic

So lets take this code:

```
{
    if(b){
        if(c)
            return f();
    }else{
        a = fa();
        fun(a);
        return funb(a);
    }

    a = fa();
    return funb(a);
}
```

The problem here for me is, this code is not very clean and simply looks ugly. That´s why I changed it to this:

```
{
    if(b){
        if(c)
            return f();
    }
    a = fa();

    if(!b){
        fun(a);
    }

    return funb(a);
}
```

But the problem here is the double check of boolean b, which is not a function, but simply a boolean variable (so not calculation necessary).

My question is how can I improve this code to make it clean, DRY and don´t double check the boolean. This code is performance critical and thus this if does make a difference.

Comment: the last 2 lines of your first sample will never get run

Comment: Why are you so against `else`?

Comment: `if(<condition>) { return <something>;}` will not continue on if the condition is met, so no `else` is needed.

Comment: choice only one language unless it's necessary.

Comment: Yeah - 'if(b) return f();' is good.  Don't even need the braces.

Comment: Compile your time critical code with warnings enabled and I betcha it would have let you know you have unreachable code...

Comment: sorry my example wasn't complete. I updated it

Comment: Question seems to have fundamentally changed with the addition of the nested if statement.  Probably nullifies most of the answers.

Comment: If you could flesh this out to a more complete example, it would probably be a better fit for CodeReview.stackexchange.com. SO is not really appropriate for questions about style of working code.

Comment: I don't think there's really a good way to refactor this. Anything you do is going to be complicated in some way.

Comment: with regards to performance, any modern compiler will reorder your tests to be as efficient as possible regardless of how you write the code. Write the code so you (and others) can read and maintain it.

Comment: Please don't edit questions in such a way as to invalidate exiting answers - it's very annoying and unfriendly.  Copy/paste code that you have tested, don't transcribe it manually, else you will likely waste everybody's time with typos:(

Comment: @MartinJames the answers are now in contradiction with the original question and actual state... Your rollback is worse.

Comment: @MartinJames On the one hand, I agree that OP should not change the substance of the question after answers have been posted. On the other hand, the original code (which you've now restored) was clearly just wrong. It's one of the hazards of being the FGIW that you'll answer a question before it's in final form.

Comment: Which is to say that I agree that the OP deserves a stern reprimand, but rolling back the question was not right. It renders the question worthless and uninteresting, and invalidates the existing answers. So the rollback didn't help the situation, it just made it worse.

Comment: @MartinJames Im very sorry for the trouble. Will remember your tips for my next questions. Should I ask the question again (With proper code)?

Comment: I give up.  This whole Q&A has become a train wreck.  The question and answers have both been edited and now everything is screwed up.  SO users should not be used for incremental development of code.  Code in questions should be copy/pasted in from a tested version.  I'm no longer going to bother with this Q&A.  If anyone wishes to roll it forward so as to invalidate a different set of comments/answers, feel free.

Answer (score 3):

This is equivalent to your first attempt:

```
{
    if (b && c)
    {
        return f();
    }
    a = fa();
    if (!b)
    {
        fun(a);
    }
    return funb(a);
}
```

Comment: I updated the answer to work with your added information.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that you can avoid checking `b` twice. But a good optimizing compiler should fix that for you in the assembly code. Here's how I would write the code:

```
{
    if (b && c)
        return f();

    a = fa();
    if (!b)
        fun(a);
    return funb(a);
}
```

Clarification: The choice here is either to check `b` twice or violate the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). I don't see any way to meet both objectives: *"DRY and don't double check the boolean"*. So my choice is to adhere to DRY, and let the compiler worry about checking `b` only once.

Comment: this is what I would do now that the OP changed the question to nullify my answer

Comment: @pm100 I was waiting to see what the real question was, since the original just seemed wrong. But Sid still beat me to it by 2 minutes, so I had to give him an upvote :)

Comment: @pm100 Seems like mine was the one with a typo.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (b) {
    if (c) {
        return f();
    }
} else {
    a = fa();
    fun(a);
    return funb(a);
}

a = fa();
return funb(a);
```

Can be rewritten

```
if (b) {
    if (c) {
        return f();
    }
    a = fa();
    return funb(a);
}
a = fa();
fun(a);
return funb(a);
```